# facing problems while checking for store data in ngrx effects before calling api

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

Hello I am new to NgRx application and having too many confusions over how I can solve this particular problem. I want to check the data in the store and if it is empty, only then I want to proceed with api call using NgRx effects.

After trying different things and spending whole day today I gave up and thought to get some expert guidance from here.

Below is my entire code:

**analytics.effects.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AnalyticsEffects {

  @Effect({dispatch: false}) loadAnalytics = this.actions$
    .pipe(
      ofType<GetAnalyticsAction>(AnalyticsTypes.GET_ANALYTICS),
      withLatestFrom(**/* cannot make this line to work */**),
      mergeMap(
        /* api call to get analytics data from server */
        () => this.analyticsService.getAnalyticsData()
          .pipe(
            map(data => {
              console.log('the data from api is...', data);
              return new GetAnalyticsAction(data)
            }),
            catchError(error => of(console.log("error in api request of analytics....")))
          )
      )
    )

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private analyticsService: AnalyticsService,
    private store$: Store<AnalyticsState>
  ) { }
}
```

**analytics.action.ts**

```
import {Action} from '@ngrx/store';
import {AnalyticsModel} from './analytics.model';
import {AnalyticsTypes} from './analytics.types';

export const GET_ANALYTICS = AnalyticsTypes.GET_ANALYTICS;

export class GetAnalyticsAction implements Action{
  readonly type = GET_ANALYTICS;
  constructor(public payload: AnalyticsModel) {
    console.log('payload sent from home is -> ', payload);
  }
}

export type Actions = GetAnalyticsAction
```

**analytics.state.ts**

```
import {AnalyticsModel} from './analytics.model';

export interface AnalyticsState {
  readonly analyticsModel: AnalyticsModel[];
}
```

**analytics.reducer.ts**

```
import {Action} from '@ngrx/store';
import {AnalyticsModel} from './analytics.model';
import * as AnalyticsAction from './../analytics/analytics.actions';

const defaultState: AnalyticsModel = {
  result: null,
}

export function reducer(state: AnalyticsModel[] = [defaultState], action: AnalyticsAction.Actions ){
  switch (action.type) {
    case AnalyticsAction.GET_ANALYTICS:
      console.log("store action type is -> ",action.type);
      console.log("store changed state is -> ",action.payload);
      return [...state, action.payload]
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**mypage.component.ts**

Finally the dispatcher which I am using to trigger respective actions in my component file:

```
  constructor(private store: Store<AnalyticsState>) {
    this.analyticsModel = store.select( state => {state.analyticsModel} );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new ActionGetAnalytics.GetAnalyticsAction(this.newAnalyticsItem));
    this.newAnalyticsItem = { result: [] };
  }
```

**What I Want**

All i want is to know that how can I make use of `withLatestFrom` in effects.ts file above to check if the data stored in the store is empty or not before I hit the api using mergeMap. I dont want application to load api repeatedly if there is no change in data stored in the store.

**What I tried**

I completely exhausted myself looking for different options from official documentations and also referring to some of the same questions posted here. But nothing came to my rescue as I simply cannot understand what sort of arguments as per my code will get into 'withLatestFrom' that can help me conditionally check for the existing data.

Please help me out if you have any pointers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out my post [Start using ngrx/effects for this](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/start-using-ngrx-effects-for-this#4-using-a-selector-inside-your-effects).

```
@Effect()
shipOrder = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<ShipOrder>(ActionTypes.ShipOrder),
  map(action => action.payload),
  concatMap(action =>
    of(action).pipe(
      withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getUserName)))
    )
  ),
  map([payload, username] => {
    ...
  })
)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the reference. From your code I am having some trouble understanding this line: `withLatestFrom(this.store.pipe(select(getUserName)))` where exactly is getUserName defined ? is it action or some method? 

Also, in the map function right in the next line `map([payload, username] => {}` how exactly are we getting payload and username? I want to know this because that's how i can fit in my code.

Lastly, is there a way i can view full code used in your link?

Comment: getUserName is a selector to retrieve the username from the store. withLatestFrom returns an array, in this example the first element is the action, the second the retrieved username

Comment: yea that part I figured it out, but I don't get this line `map([payload, username] => {})` where are payload and username coming from? from where i can get correct values in this arguments, in my case map is not accepting such arguments. Sorry, but this is extremely confusing.

Comment: Read the docs for more info https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom